# How to check Query is null inside IF condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to check query inside the condition

I want the value 'NO' if query is null and 'YES' if query is not null

by trying in if condition I get error.

My query is

```
SELECT Count(SiteID)
from ChartFace 
Inner Join Structure on Structure.StructureID = ChartFace.StructureID
where (ContractNumber='C197960' AND LineNumber=4) 
  AND (ISNULL('MN420628', '-1')='-1' or SiteID = 'MN420628')
```

What I tried

```
IF(above query is NULL) THEN 'NO'
ELSE 'YES'
END IF
```

Later I need this in my select statement

```
Select ContractID, ContractName, IF(above query is NULL) THEN 'NO'
ELSE 'YES' AS Status FROM Contract
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this for MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? The 2 are quite different. YOu have `ISNULL('MN420628', '-1')`, which infers SQL Sevrer, but then an `IF` in your `SELECT`, which infers MySQL. `ISNULL()` has 1 parameter on MySQL, but `IF()` doesn't exist on SQL Server (It's only a Logical Flow operator, not a Function). I've removed the conflicting tags; please tetag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: It is SQL Server

Comment: `COUNT` returns a number >= 0. It can never be NULL. I surmise you want to know whether the query finds a matching row or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **mysql** you can use **exist**

Like

```
SELECT  ContractID, ContractName,IF( EXISTS(
SELECT 
    Count(SiteID)
FROM ChartFace 
    INNER JOIN Structure ON Structure.StructureID = ChartFace.StructureID
WHERE (ContractNumber='C197960' AND LineNumber=4) AND 
    (ISNULL('MN420628', '-1')='-1' or SiteID = 'MN420628')),'yes','No') Status 
FROM Contract ;
```

in **SQL Server** it is similiar Like

```
SELECT ContractID, ContractName,CASE
     WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 
    Count(SiteID)
FROM ChartFace 
    INNER JOIN Structure ON Structure.StructureID = ChartFace.StructureID
WHERE (ContractNumber='C197960' AND LineNumber=4) AND 
    (ISNULL('MN420628', '-1')='-1' or SiteID = 'MN420628')) THEN 'yes'
     ELSE 'NO'
   END as  Status 
FROM Contract ;
```

Comment: MY first answer is only valid for mysql , but the second should work in ms sqlserver. you didin't post any data s or Version

Comment: Nope. `SELECT COUNT(…)` without `GROUP BY` returns exactly one row. So `Status` is *always* `'yes'` in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ContractID, ContractName,  case when SiteCount > 0 then 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as Status
FROM Contract c
left join (
    SELECT ContractNumber, Count(SiteID) as SiteCount
    from ChartFace 
    Inner Join Structure on Structure.StructureID = ChartFace.StructureID
    where (ContractNumber='C197960' AND LineNumber=4) 
      AND (ISNULL('MN420628', '-1')='-1' or SiteID = 'MN420628')
    group by ContractNumber
  )  tbl on c.ContractNumber = tbl.ContractNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) is what you are after.

```
SELECT ContractID, ContractName,
 CASE
  WHEN COUNT(SiteID) IS 0 THEN 'NO'
  ELSE 'YES'
 END AS HasSite
FROM ChartFace
 INNER JOIN Structure on Structure.StructureID = ChartFace.StructureID
 WHERE ContractNumber='C197960' AND LineNumber=4
 AND (ISNULL('MN420628', '-1')='-1' or SiteID = 'MN420628')
```

This would return something like:

```
{ ContractID:  3, ContractName: 'REALLY IMPORTANT CONTRACT', HasSite: 'NO' }
```

Comment: NO, this is invalid SQL. You cannot select `ContractID`, `ContractName`, and `COUNT(SiteID)` without `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Corrected "COUNT(SiteID) IS NULL" to "COUNT(SiteID) IS 0"

Comment: `IS 0` is wrong. It must be `= 0`, if you want to compare with zero. But the whole query is invalid. You cannot access *one* row's `ContractID` and `ContractName` at the same time as the `COUNT` over *all* rows (without using window functions or making the two columns an aggregation group with `GROUP BY` that is).

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(*)` can never be null. You can compare it with zero though:

```
select
  contractid,
  contractname, 
  case when
    (
      select count(*)
      from chartface cf
      join structure s on s.structureid = cf.structureid
      where cf.contractnumber = c.contractid
      and ...
    ) = 0 then 'NO' else 'YES' end as status
from contract c
order by contractid;
```

But if you want to check for mere existence, why count at all? We use `EXISTS` or `IN` in SQL for this:

```
select
  contractid,
  contractname, 
  case when contractid in
    (
      select cf.contractnumber
      from chartface cf
      join structure s on s.structureid = cf.structureid
      where  ...
    ) then 'YES' else 'NO' end as status
from contract
order by contractid;
```